# onResume() called twice in a row after onCreate() > onPause()

Tags: android, lifecycle, android-lifecycle, onresume, onpause

I've run into a weird occurrence with regards to my child activity's life-cycle methods. If I launch and close the activity enough times, there eventually comes a point where for some reason, upon launching, `onPause` gets called immediately after `onCreate` (skipping `onResume`), which is then followed by `onResume` being called twice in a row. This ends up causing a `RuntimeException` in my `onResume`.

Here's the code that starts my activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecorderActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, AV_CAPTURE);
```

My onPause:

```
protected void onPause() {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    super.onPause();
};
```

I'm not really sure what else I can provide here, it's all pretty straightforward. `finish()` is called to close the activity, etc.

I should also probably mention that the activity is being triggered from a Javascript Interface attached to a WebView. Another interesting thing to mention is that setting a breakpoint anywhere in the first code block above seems to prevent the issue from happening.

Comment: But is it a problem, actually?

Comment: I mean, I could probably work around it by wrapping `Camera.open()` in a try catch, but I'd really like to know what's going on.

Comment: I see. @Uxonith post makes complete sense as anyway exceptions should be catched. I think, without being sure, that the lauching/closing of activities is too fast so the device is overwhelmed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter how fast I do it though.

Comment: Strange. I have re-read this and it seems that there is no guarantee that onPause() / onResume() are called just once. Just a guarantee they are called, and just an expectation they are once. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 3):

While I do not have an answer for the resume being called twice, I do have a link to the Android docs stating that you should always check for exceptions while attempting to open the camera.  See here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#access-camera

In your onPause, make sure that you set your Camera object to null.  Then in onResume, only attempt to call getCameraInstance() if your camera is not null.